# In the blink of an eye

Tags: meaning, idioms

I wanted to say - time flies very fast with the usage of the idiom "in the blink of an eye".  The sentence goes like this - Time flies like in the blink of an eye. Is this the correct usage of the idiom?

Comment: Isn’t the idiom *in the **wink** of an eye*? I’ve heard the blinkered version. The OED has an entry for ‘in a wink’ to mean ‘in a trice’.

Comment: I think it's effectively a [mixed metaphor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mixed+metaphor). But it belongs on writers.se anyway.

Comment: A related question [re: articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/do-idioms-pose-an-exception-to-normal-definite-and-indefinite-article-usage) which discusses specifically 'in [article] blink of [article] eye'.

Answer (score 8):

*In the blink of an eye* is a very short time in its literal sense. There is no need to use "like" here— it isn't *like* an instant, it *is* an instant.

*Time flies* is an idiom which evokes the general sense that it moves quickly, and more quickly than we perceive it, but not necessarily in an instant. The old saying is *Time flies when you're having fun,* meaning time seems to pass more quickly when having fun, but  not that the fun is over with as soon as it started.

They are both clichés, and I would try to think of better expressions perhaps more directly related to the topic. If you do use one, remove the other, as they are redundant. You could say, for example,

> My first year at university passed in the blink of an eye.
>
> Time flew during my first year at university.

Comment: Time flies like an arrow.  Fruit flies like a banana.

Answer (score 4):

> *Time flew during my first year at university.*
>
> *My first year at university passed in the blink of an eye.*

Grammatically, these are good examples, but I'd like to expound.

***Time flew*** implies time went by quickly.

***In the blink on an eye*** implies something happens in an instant, such as a sudden, unforeseen calamity.

Hence, I have no problem with "*Time flew during my first year at university*," but it's hard to resolve a one-year event happening *in the blink of an eye*.

So, I would suggest:

> Time flew during my first year at the university.
>
> Things were going well during my second year at the university, then, in the blink of an eye, my world was turned upside-down.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Something that happens very quickly can be said to happen in the blink of an eye, but not time itself.

Answer (score 1):

the **wink** of an eye, or the **blink** of an eye?

[Here's an Ngram:](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twinkling%20of%20an%20eye,blink%20of%20an%20eye,wink%20of%20an%20eye&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]

Comment: So one is a new fad, and the other has been around for centuries.  Got it.

Comment: @tchrist - It might be as you say (new & old versions) or might not, in that both phrases have some other, disjoint uses -- a wink as a signal, a blink as a reaction -- that confound the issue slightly.

Comment: The King James Bible has: "In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump" (I Cor 15:52)